# Postal address validation using haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

i am extremely new to Haskell..

i want to validate postal address using Haskell.

```
29b, roadname, cityname, postalcode, country
```

i want to validate the following
1)first section (29b)must have at least a number at start.
2)roadname, cityname, country are characters.
3)postal code is of 6 digits either a character or a integer.
4) each of them are separated by comma(,)

i started tried this , but i was unable to do it.

```
validtion :: String -> Bool
validtion [] = []
validtion (x:xs)
        |(isInt :xs) = validtion xs
        |(',':xs) = validtion xs
validtion (x:xs)= x: validtion xs
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is clearly a homework and you haven't paid any attempt at reading Haskell docs, I'll only hand-wave some hints and clues here and will fill the answer at the end of the month.

First thing, no value (function in your case) in Haskell can start with a capital letter. So `Validtion` (don't know why you constantly miss the `a`) is invalid identifier.

Then, you cannot have both `=` and guards, not to mention that the guards must be aligned on the same column.

Third, `(isInt : xs)` means a list with at least one element, that first element can be referred to by `isInt` and all other elements by `xs`. Similarly, `',':xs` means a string which starts with `,`.

Now, how to solve it: you need a function `String -> Bool` but since `String` has several parts you need to split it in words and remove the `,`s. Search on [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?) for `String -> [String]` and `String -> String -> String` to find out what functions to use.

Now, having a list `[String]` you need to validate each element of that list in part. Import `Data.Char` and use functions from there together with `map`.

Finally, from a list `[Bool]` to get a `Bool` you go again to [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?) and search for `[Bool] -> Bool`.

PS: Have a look at [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/). They are both good resources for learning and freely available on the internet.